# Why is it possible to compare incompatible types by reference in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, types, comparison

Check out this snippet:

```
    List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,Boolean> m = new HashMap<>();
    if( c == m ) //no error here!  WHY?
    {
        c = m; //"Incompatible types" error, as expected.
        m = c; //"Incompatible types" error, as expected.
    }
```

**How come `c == m` gives no error?**

I am using the javac of jdk1.8.0.20 and I have no reason to suspect that it disregards the java language specification, so this is with a fairly absolute level of certainty in the spec, so:

What is the point / purpose / usefulness of having something like this allowed by the spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's permitted specifically because `List` and `Map` are interfaces.

We could imagine some class

```
// (please only imagine)
class ListMap implements List, Map {...}
```

Compile-time legality of reference equality ([15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3)) is the same as that of reference type casting ([5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)). In short, since you can generally cast between any reference type and an interface, you can also generally compare reference equality of any type to an interface.

The permission seems more useful in the context of smaller interfaces like `Comparable`, `Serializable`, `Iterable`, etc., where a class is more likely to implement more than one.

Answer (score 4):

Just because the types are inconvertible doesn't mean that are not equal objects.  If the types are "Inconvertible" it means a cast is required to check the type is actually convertible.

```
interface Outputer extends Consumer<String>, Serializable { }

Outputer out = System.out::println;
Consumer<String> cs = out;
Serializable s = out;
System.out.println(s == cs); // prints true

// s = cs; // Inconvertible types, doesn't compile
s = (Serializable) cs; // compiles and runs fine.
```

`cs` and `s` are inconvertible types, yet they point to the same object and this prints `true`

Answer (score 1):

The `Incompatible types` error appears because when the assignment is being triggered, an operation called [Assignment conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) starts. What it does is:

> Assignment conversion occurs when the value of an expression is assigned (§15.26) to a variable: the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.

If the conversion fails, then a compile-time error is thrown.

However, an compile-time error is not thrown when the [== operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) takes place.

Comment: The link you cite for the `==` operator has this:  **It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal.**

Comment: The result will not necessarily be false, as Peter Lawrey and Radiodef have shown in their answers.

Comment: True. I removed the last sentence. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Java, whenever you have objects, the system uses pointers.  And when you use `==` on two objects, it compares their *pointers*.  In other words, it checks whether the two pointers are pointing to the same object in memory. This is always a safe check to make.

Also, it should be noted that when inheritance (and [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)) is involved, it is possible to have multiple pointers of different types that point to the same object.  Of course, that wasn't the case in your example.  But as I said earlier, it is harmless to check whether two pointers are pointing to the same object since that check makes no assumptions about the classes involved.

Answer (score -5):

When you write

```
if(c==m)
```

you are simply checking for @hashcode Which might be same for two object under certain circumstances so you might not be getting any error in that line!

Comment: `==` doesn't compare hash codes. `==` will never evaluate to true when comparing two different objects.

Comment: It goes to show how high the quality of stackoverflow.com is, that we come across such bad answers so rarely.  Let's see how many awful mistakes in just one short sentence: 1. no, this is not checking for hashcode, it is comparing by reference; 2. no, the references of different objects will always be different;  3. the concept of a compile-time error is totally unrelated to the concept of a runtime comparison; 4. the question is asking why I am not getting an error, so it is useless to tell me that I might not be getting any error.